# Android device receives endless push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

Our server sends one push notification to a device. The notification arrives and the user does not delete the message. Now the same message arrives at the device in a one minute cycle. We checked and our server only sends one message. Does the GCM resend notifications?

Comment: GCM only retries only if the device is offline initially, else it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found it. It's a setting on the Samsung Galaxy:

**Settings > Accessibility > Notification Reminder > ON**

It's possible to set the interval. Ours happened to be 1 minute.